# How to keep file after being processed in source folder vfs transport WSO2

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I use VFS transport in WSO2 to route file from one folder to another.
 But now I'm facing a problem, I do not want to move the processed file to another folder or delete it. 
The problem is VFS transport has a default action DELETE or move processed file to another folder.
 Is it possible to keep the processed file in the source folder? Or do I have to change the code or modify something else? Is there any other way to do this?
 
FYI, my proxy looks like this,

```
<proxy name="XXX" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <class name="com.test.read"/>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="status" value="file read"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///source</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///target</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

After the file is processed, the file will be moved to folder target. So how can I keep the file without moving or delete it?
Thanks :)

Comment: can you add your config file

Comment: @itsmeisuru I edited my question and add the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess to original location, which will keep the file there even after being processed.

```
<proxy name="XXX" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <class name="com.test.read"/>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="status" value="file read"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///source</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///source</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Hey, but won't it make the same file processed again? I don't want the same file to be processed again :)

Comment: Yes.. Since the proxy service is listening on that location, what ever file remains there will be picked.

Comment: so, is there any other way to keep my files in the folder without being processed again?

Comment: @Mari_Yaguchi you can keep a reference when processing the file using class mediator, then you can check it before process.